# Plupload, angular and waiting for submit button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, plupload

I have a form that needs to upload a number of images to a server. Using [this angular plupload](https://github.com/remotty/angular-plupload) directive, I have a working demo...sort of.

Using this in my view:

```
<a plupload="vm.fileUpload.url" 
   plupload-options="vm.fileUpload.options" 
   plupload-callbacks="vm.fileUpload.callbacks">
   Upload Button
</a>
```

And this in my controller:

```
vm.fileUpload = {
    url: 'http://localhost:29365/api/building',
    callbacks: {
        filesAdded: function(uploader, files) {
            vm.loading = true;
            $timeout(function() {
                uploader.start();
            }, 1);
        },
        uploadProgress: function(uploader, file) {
            vm.loading = file.percent/100.0;
        },
        fileUploaded: function(uploader, file, response) {
            vm.loading = false;
            vm.uploadedFiles.push(file);
            console.log('Upload Complete!');
        },
        error: function(uploader, error) {
            vm.loading = false;
            console.log(error.message);
        }
    }
}
```

I can get upload files to my server (ASP.NET API, in this case). The images are sent, I can see them. Hooray.

The problem is, all those images get sent the moment I select them. It's there in the `filesAdded` callback. For my purposes, this is a bad thing. I have other form data that I'd like to send along with the images and I'd also like to give the user an opportunity to change their mind and delete the image before it's sent to the server.

So, I'd like for plupload to get the images ready, and then wait for the user to hit the submit button before anything gets sent.

Is there something along the lines of a `submitted` callback I can set on a button? Can it be used with [the directive I mentioned earlier](https://github.com/remotty/angular-plupload)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a good answer for this question. Plupload does what it does and it doesn't want to be included in another form. It can be set to have it's own submit button, but I don't think there's an easy way to get it to use the form's submit button.